# creating flowcharts/pseudocode

Tags: c#

I have a flowchart homework that I need help with getting started. I am very new to programming and started by taking a class online. Here is the homework question:
"The Dorian Gray Portrait Studio charges its customers based on the number of subjects who pose for a portrait. The fee schedule is as follows:
subjects in portrait/ Base price

1. 1/ $100
2. 2/ $130
3. 3/ $150
4. 4/ $165
5. 5/ $175
6. 6/ $180
7. 7 or more/ $185.

Portrait sittings on Saturday or sunday cost 20 percent more than the base price. Design a flow chart or pseudocode for the program that accepts the following data: the last name of the family sitting for the portrait, the number of subjects in the portrait, and the scheduled day of the week. Display all the input data as well as the calculated sitting fee.
I just need a starting point of how to do this. My text book is hard to understand and it is not helping me at all.
Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart for a description of the various shapes and examples.

Answer (score 1):

### List out the following:

> - What are the **facts** you have been given?
> - What **activities** were described?
> - What are the **statements** you can make about those activities?
> - How many **processes** are there to keep track of?
> - What are the **steps** for each process, beginning to end?
> - What is **variable** and when does it need to be considered?
> - What **decisions** must be made before, during and after those processes?

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode might go something like this. You have to fill in the ... parts.

```
; read input data
read lastName
...
; calculate fee
if numberOfSubjects is 1 then fee is 100
else if ...
; adjust for week day
...
; print input data & fee
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a key of a common program flowchart:

[image: key]

So then the beginning of your flow chart will look something like this:

[image: flowchart]

From there I think you can figure out how to end your flow chart, based the key.

An example of I flowchart for a program I have used:

[image: flowchart eg.]

As for pseudo-code, I would recommend a [`switch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t(v=vs.80).aspx) statement for your real code, but your real code will look something like:

```
string lastname;
string dayOfWeek;
int numberOfPortraits, cost;
...
lastname = Console.ReadLine();
numberOfPortraits = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
dayOfWeek = Console.ReadLine();
...
switch (numberOfPortraits)
{
    case 0:
        cost = 0;
        break;

    case 1:
        cost = 100;
        break;

    ...

    default:
        cost = 185;
        break;
}

return cost;
```

You could also use [`if-else if`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h(v=vs.110).aspx) like [dschultz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12658009/creating-flowcharts-pseudocode/12658051#12658051) said, and is easier for a beginner to learn, but more advanced things you should use `switch`. But that can become overwhelming and a switch statement can be more clear. See [Continuous If statements](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/11718/continues-if-statements) to see how messy that can become.

Comment: For a beginner the if if_else condition is better understood than switch case. In this example with few conditions it is adequate. Also the second part (sat,sun) has not been addressed